# Display only checkbox based on boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This should be a simple question but I have searched and cannot find the answer. I have an **index** view where I would like to display some boolean values in a table, as check boxes and display-only.

The code below displays a check box but it can be modified, also it doesn't display the value based on the **cosmic.ampliseq** which is a **boolean**.

```
<% @cosmics.each do |cosmic| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box cosmic.ampliseq, "disabled", {}, "false", "true" %></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @cosmics.each do |cosmic| %>
  <tr>   
   <td><%= check_box "cosmiq", "ampliseq", {:checked => cosmic.ampliseq, :disabled => true}%></td>
```

Refer [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box)

Comment: Adding anything to the :checked attribute checks the box. s.krueger has the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
<% @cosmics.each do |cosmic| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag :ampliseq, "1", cosmic.ampliseq, disabled: true %></td>
```

Syntax:
`check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`